# Where does Chromium load extensions?

Tags: electron, chromium

I'm trying to get a number of Chrome extensions working in an Electron app. Electron only supports dev tools extensions, so I'm writing code to handle regular extensions more-or-less from scratch. But, I'm getting stuck figuring out what's involved in getting the content scripts to run in the same way they do in Chrome.

In the existing Electron implementation, which is expressly limited to development tool extensions, I traced the code to [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/bb2ab01f99fb790f0d271211c1c3572ed4511e02/lib/browser/chrome-extension.js#L392), specifically, line 392:

win.devToolsWebContents.executeJavaScript(`Extensions.extensionServer._addExtension(${JSON.stringify(extensionInfo)})`)

Finding the next step in this process has proved very challenging. I think, but am not certain, that [HERE](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/77578ccb4082ae20a9326d9e673225f1189ebb63/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/extensions/ExtensionServer.js#L688) is the corresponding Chromium code, but this seems like it's for development tools extensions in particular (what with the calls to `InspectorFrontendHost` and the use of iframes).

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Where is the code where Chromium loads the content scripts for regular extensions? Or is this that code?

Comment: Not all Chrome extensions will run in Electron, if they have used Chrome extension APIs--which is not supported by Electron. Devtools' extension should run.

Comment: I am well aware of this. The "work-around" is to find which Chrome extension APIs a given extension needs, and appropriately re-impliment them. This is how the extensions that *are* supported by Electron function, since it's mostly just messaging to the background. The electron-chrome-extension library by GetStation implements more of those APIs. In both cases the internal Chromium code that is invoked to load the extensions is the code linked in my question, which appears to itself be code specifically for loading dev tools extensions. Hence my question. I will update my question for clarity.